# How can I change the background color of Elevated Button in Flutter from function?

Tags: flutter, android-studio-4.2, flutter-functional-widget

I am new to Flutter, and I started Flutter last week. And now I want to make a simple Xylophone application. I created the UI successfully and made a function `playSound(int soundNumber)`, but when I call this function for playing sound, it gives me this error.

> The following _TypeError was thrown building Body(dirty, state: _BodyState#051c2): 
> type '_MaterialStatePropertyAll' is not a subtype of type 'MaterialStateProperty<Color?>?'

Here's the code I wrote for the `playSound(int soundNumber)` function.

```
void playSound(int soundNumber) {
  final player = AudioCache();
  player.play('note$soundNumber.wav');
}

Expanded buildPlayButton({MaterialStateProperty color, int soundNumber}) {
  return Expanded(
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        playSound(soundNumber);
      },
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: color,
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Here is the point where I am calling this function.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
    children: <Widget>[
      buildPlayButton(color: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red), soundNumber: 1),
      buildPlayButton(color: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.orangeAccent), soundNumber: 2),
      buildPlayButton(color: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.yellow), soundNumber: 3),
      buildPlayButton(color: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.indigo), soundNumber: 4),
      buildPlayButton(color: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.blue), soundNumber: 5),
      buildPlayButton(color: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.lightGreenAccent), soundNumber: 6),
      buildPlayButton(color: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green), soundNumber: 7),
    ],
  );
}
```

How can I call this function, because it gives me the above-mentioned error?

Answer (score 297, accepted):

You can style ElevatedButton by using the styleFrom static method or the ButtonStyle class. The first one is more convenient than the second one.

**Using styleFrom to style an ElevatedButton:**

```
ElevatedButton(
      child: Text('Button'),
      onPressed: () {},
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom({
           Color backgroundColor, // set the background color
           Color foregroundColor,
           Color disabledForegroundColor,
           Color shadowColor,
           double elevation,
           TextStyle textStyle,
           EdgeInsetsGeometry padding,
           Size minimumSize,
           BorderSide side,
           OutlinedBorder shape,
           MouseCursor enabledMouseCursor,
           MouseCursor disabledMouseCursor,
           VisualDensity visualDensity,
           MaterialTapTargetSize tapTargetSize,
           Duration animationDuration,
           bool enableFeedback
     }),
),
```

**Example:**

```
ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Button'),
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                backgroundColor: Colors.purple,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 50, vertical: 20),
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                fontSize: 30,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
),
```

**Using ButtonStyle to style an ElevatedButton:**

```
style: ButtonStyle({
  MaterialStateProperty<TextStyle> textStyle,
  MaterialStateProperty<Color> backgroundColor,
  MaterialStateProperty<Color> foregroundColor,
  MaterialStateProperty<Color> overlayColor,
  MaterialStateProperty<Color> shadowColor,
  MaterialStateProperty<double> elevation,
  MaterialStateProperty<EdgeInsetsGeometry> padding,
  MaterialStateProperty<Size> minimumSize,
  MaterialStateProperty<BorderSide> side,
  MaterialStateProperty<OutlinedBorder> shape,
  MaterialStateProperty<MouseCursor> mouseCursor,
  VisualDensity visualDensity,
  MaterialTapTargetSize tapTargetSize,
  Duration animationDuration,
  bool enableFeedback
})
```

**Example**

```
ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Button'),
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
                padding: MaterialStateProperty.all(EdgeInsets.all(50)),
                textStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(TextStyle(fontSize: 30))),
),
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I do not understand why I cannot do Theme.of(context).elevatedButtonTheme.copyWith(backgroundColor: ...) The elevatedButtonTheme is null at runtime. I do not get why, as other themes aren't null...

Comment: property "primary" to set the background color is deprecated now. Use "backgroundColor" instead.

Comment: getting error `'primary' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use backgroundColor instead. This feature was deprecated after v3.1.0.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.`

Answer (score 77):

Pass color as parameter and use *MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(color)* to specify the color.

```
buildPlayButton(color: Colors.red, soundNumber: 1)
```

```
Expanded buildPlayButton({Color color, int soundNumber}){
  return Expanded(
    child: ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        playSound(soundNumber);
      },
      style: ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(color),
      ),
    ),
);}
```

#### Sample button

[image: Elevated Button]

**In general**

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.red, // background
    onPrimary: Colors.yellow, // foreground
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: Text('ElevatedButton with custom foreground/background'),
)
```

Sample button

[image: ElevatedButton with custom foreground/background]

Reference:

[ElevatedButton class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ElevatedButton-class.html)

Comment: which arguments i have to pass when adding this inside a function?

Comment: I've updated the post. Pass color as parameter and use MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(color) to specify the color.

Comment: thanks @hbamithkumara ... it worked like a charm...

Comment: `primary` and `onPrimary` no longer exist. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74025736/480982

Answer (score 19):

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: resetHandler,
               child: Text("button"),
               style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.amber),),
```

Comment: style:Elevatedbutton.styleFrom(primary:Colors.amber)

Comment: getting error - `'primary' is deprecated and shouldn't be used. Use backgroundColor instead. This feature was deprecated after v3.1.0.
Try replacing the use of the deprecated member with the replacement.`

Comment: `primary` and `onPrimary` no longer exist. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74025736/480982

Answer (score 17):

Just use `MaterialStateProperty.all(**YOUR COLOR**)`:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Button'),
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ButtonStyle(
                backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),)
),
```

or like this:
Just use `ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: **YOUR COLOR**)`:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
            child: Text('Button'),
            onPressed: () {},
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary: Colors.red),
)
```

Comment: `primary` and `onPrimary` no longer exist. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74025736/480982

Answer (score 14):

You have three options to change the background color:

**ElevatedButton.styleFrom:**

If you just want to change the background color and foreground color irrespective of the states then you can do as given below.

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    primary: Colors.red, // Background
    onPrimary: Colors.white, // Foreground
  ),
  onPressed: () { },
  child: Text('custom foreground/background'),
)
```

**MaterialStateProperty.all:**

to override a ElevatedButtons default background(text/icon) color for all states.

```
 ElevatedButton(style:
    ButtonStyle(
      backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.red),
    onPressed: () { },
    child: Text('custom foreground/background'),
    ));
```

**MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith:**

By default, the elevated button inherits a blue color. We can tweak the default style using the style parameter and ButtonStyle class.
Button has different states such as pressed, disabled, hovered, etc. You can change the style for each state. In the below snippet, the default color of the button changes to green when it is pressed.

```
ElevatedButton(
  style: ButtonStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<Color>(
      (Set<MaterialState> states) {
        if (states.contains(MaterialState.pressed))
          return Colors.green;
        return null; // Use the component's default.
      },
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: `primary` and `onPrimary` no longer exist. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/74025736/480982

Answer (score 10):

Suppose we need to change Elevated Button Background color then? Elevated Button has a style Property And style property need ButtonStyle(). ButtonStyle has backgroundColor property which requires MaterialStateProperty. You can simply assign background color by MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green). Let’s explore examples of Background color of Elevated Button in Flutter.

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            print('Button Pressed');
          },
          style: ButtonStyle(
            backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.green),
          ),
          child: Text('Send'),
        ),
```

Answer (score 10):

The current best answer with the example of `ElevatedButton.styleFrom` is outdated. As of Flutter v3.1.0, the primary parameter is deprecated.

```dart
Color? primary // Use foregroundColor instead. This feature was deprecated after v3.1.0.
```

Instead, use the `backgroundColor` parameter:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
    backgroundColor: const Colors.red,
  ),
  onPressed: () {},
  child: const Text('Test'),
)
```

Answer (score 7):

**Screenshot:**

[image]

---

**Code:**

```dart
class _MyState extends State<MyPage> {
  bool _flag = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () => setState(() => _flag = !_flag),
          child: Text(_flag ? 'Red' : 'Green'),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            backgroundColor: _flag ? Colors.red : Colors.teal, // This is what you need!
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can simply use this code inside the `ElevatedButton`

```dart
 style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
       backgroundColor:Theme.of(context).primaryColor
    ),
```

Answer (score 5):

```
body:Center(

  child: ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () {},
     child: Text("click me"),
      style:ButtonStyle(
        backgroundColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.green))
     ),


  ),
```

}
}

Answer (score 4):

```
 style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(30.0),
                        ),
                          primary: HexColor(HexColor.primarycolor),
                          textStyle: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
```

Answer (score 3):

```
style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(primary : Colors.black),
```

Answer (score 3):

```
ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: (){},
          child: Text('comprar'),
          style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
            primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColor
          )
        )
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 3):

Use styleFrom of ElevatedButton

```
 ElevatedButton(
      onPressed: (){},
      child: Text('click me'),
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(backgroundColor: Colors.green),
    ),
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `primary` property (inside a style) and assign it a color, but be careful, if you haven't set your `onPressed()` event then the color doesn't change..

Here is an example:

```
Widget renderMyButton() {
  return ElevatedButton(
      style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.lightBlue, // Change the color here..
        elevation: 0,
        // ...
      ),

      onPressed: () {}, // This line is important to change the ElevatedButton color..
      child: Container()
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
style: ButtonStyle({  
  MaterialStateProperty.all(backgroundColor),   
),
```

Similarly, you can add `MaterialStateProperty.all(<Value here>)` to most properties of elevated button(elevation, padding, border etc).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to add `onPressed: () {},`

Otherwise the color will be gray.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Add where? Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the elevated button background color and outline color also with the shape of the circle, then checkout this code:

```
ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        side: BorderSide(
            width: 1,
            color: primaryBlue),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius:
                BorderRadius.circular(
          20,
        ))),
    onPressed: () {},
    child: Text(
      'Use camera',
      style: t3b,
    ),
),
```

This code will look like this:

[image]

Answer (score -1):

ElevatedButton(
style: ButtonStyle(backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll(Colors.orange)),
onPressed: null,);

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).